# Tkinter vertical scale inverted

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I am using a tkinter vertical scale.

[image]

Values increase as the slider moves down and decrease as the slider moves up.

I need the inverse behavior, so moving the slider up increases the value.

In the documentation there is a way of making the scale Horizontal, but I cannot find a way of inverting the direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the from /  to values? so from would be 100 to would be 0

Comment: Yeah, seems to work. If you post it as a solution I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: By the way if anybody can tell me why the downvotes? The proposed solution is not in the documentation, I don't see the question to be repeated and the proposed solution is not obvious (setting the initial value higher than the end value doees not work in other scenarios like `range`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter scale http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm has options `from` and `to` you can set `from` to a value higher than `to` to inverse the slider.

For example the default `from` is `0` and the default `to` is `100`, to set these on initialization you would do:

```
myscalewidget = tk.Scale(parent, from = 100, to = 0)
```

or by `config`:

```
myscalewidget.config(from = 100, to = 0)
```

Comment: to quote effbot: "[...] Note that to pass the `from` option as a keyword argument, you need to add a trailing underscore (`from` is a reserved keyword in Python)." -- i.e. use `from_=100`